# show that there exist an $F_{\sigma}$-set $U$ and a $G_{\delta}$-set $V$ such that $U\subset A\subset V$ and $\mu(V-U)=0$

Tags: measure-theory

> Suppose $\mu$ is a measure in $\large{R}^k$ such that bounded sets have finite measure. Given $A$, show that there exist an $F_{\sigma}$-set $U$ (a countable union of closed sets) and a $G_{\delta}$-set $V$ (a countable intersection of open sets) such that $U\subset A\subset V$ and $\mu(V-U)=0$.

I think I have use the following theorem: $\mu(A)<\infty$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists a closed $C$ an open $G$ such that $C\subset A\subset G$ and $\mu(G-C)< \epsilon$.

But I have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the theorem which you mentioned, there exists for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ a closed set $C_n$ and an open set $G_n$ such that $C_n \subseteq A \subseteq G_n$ and $\mu(G_n \backslash C_n) \leq 2^{-n}$. Without loss of generality, the sets $C_n$ are increasing in $n$ and the sets $G_n$ are decreasing in $n$ (otherwise consider $\tilde{C}_n = \bigcup_{j=1}^n C_j$ and $\tilde{G}_n = \bigcap_{j=1}^n G_j$). Set

$$V := \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} G_n \quad \text{and} \quad U := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} C_n.$$

By definition, $V$ is a $G_{\delta}$-set, $U$ is an $F_{\sigma}$-set and $U \subseteq A \subseteq V$. Since $G_n \downarrow V$, it follows from the continuity of the measure that

$$\mu(V \setminus U) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \mu \left( \bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty} G_n \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n \right).$$
Since

$$\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty} G_n \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n  \subseteq \bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty} (G_n \setminus C_n),$$

this gives

\begin{align*} \mu(V  \setminus U) &\leq \limsup_{N \to \infty} \mu \left( \bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty} (G_n \setminus C_n) \right)\\ &\leq \limsup_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n =N}^{\infty} \underbrace{\mu(G_n \setminus C_n)}_{\leq 2^{-n}} = 0. \end{align*}

Comment: .@saz in the last second line  why $\mu ( \bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty} (G_n \setminus C_n))  =\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}{\mu(G_n \setminus C_n)} ?$

I think $\mu ( \bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty} (G_n \setminus C_n))  =\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}{\mu(G_n \setminus C_n)} $