# why $ \mu \left( \bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty} (G_n \setminus C_n) \right)= \sum_{n =N}^{\infty} {\mu(G_n \setminus C_n)}?$

Tags: measure-theory

In theorem $2.17$ Rudin say that  If $E\in\frak M$, there are sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ is an $F_\sigma, B$ is a $G_\delta$, $A\subset E\subset B$, and $\mu(B-A)=0.$

I found  the  proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3557222/557708)

**My confusion**:In proof it is written

\begin{align*} \mu(V  \setminus U) &\leq \limsup_{N \to \infty} \mu \left( \bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty} (G_n \setminus C_n) \right)\\ &\leq \limsup_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n =N}^{\infty} \underbrace{\mu(G_n \setminus C_n)}_{\leq 2^{-n}} = 0. \end{align*}

why $\limsup_{N \to \infty} \mu \left( \bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty} (G_n \setminus C_n) \right)= \limsup_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n =N}^{\infty} {\mu(G_n \setminus C_n)}?$

I think if we replace union instead of intersection then

$\limsup_{N \to \infty} \mu \left( \bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty} (G_n \setminus C_n) \right)= \limsup_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n =N}^{\infty} {\mu(G_n \setminus C_n)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is
$$ \mu \left( \bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty} (G_n \setminus C_n) \right) \leq \sum_{n =N}^{\infty} {\mu(G_n \setminus C_n)} $$
It is "less than", not "equal to".

In fact, the sum is not even needed. The fact that
$$ \mu \left( \bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty} (G_n \setminus C_n) \right) \leq \mu(G_N \setminus C_N) \leq \frac{1}{2^N} $$
is enough to conclude the result.